# Explanation of the names of C++ std lib methods

Tags: c++, language-design

I am a Python/Scala/Haskell coder, trying to learn C++ and I am having hard time remembering anything because so many of the names of methods or classes in C++ do not make any sense to me. This is possibly because I do not understand what they actually intend to do. Can you anyone explain these for me:

1. `vector` - vector is such a odd thing to call a list or sequence of things. Why vector?
2. `unordered_set` - Why not simply a `set`? Since when are sets ordered? Doesn't set implictly mean order does not matter and the ordered version (java's TreeSets) should be explicitly called `ordered_set` instead??
3. `vector.cend` - What does cend mean? I could not find cend in the English dictionary? Why not simply call it end?
4. `emplace` - What does emplace mean? Shouldn't a better word be "insert"?
5. `push_back` - Why not simply call `push` or `append`? Isn't the "back" part implicit?
6. Why does `empty()` return a boolean? Shouldn't it be `isEmpty()`?
7. Also, the `.begin()` and `.end()` seems inconsistent. `begin()` is a verb while `end()` is a noun in this context. begin denotes to start something whereas it simply returns a pointer to start. Shouldn't the method be called either `start` which is a noun and goes well with "end" or `beginning` atleast instead of `begin`
8. Also, `list.unique` does not do at all what I think it does - It simply chops of **consecutive** similar items!?! (huge violation of principal of least astonishment) - funnily you can do unique correctly in linear run time too with an extra hashset

I have a lot more but if I grok the above, I might have an easier time learning C++. Thanks!

Comment: Not all of the names make sense, but lots of them do once you have a look at [some documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `vector`: There are vectors in functional languages too, like [this package](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Numeric_Haskell%3a_A_Vector_Tutorial)
2. `unordered_set` - Unordered/ordered refers to the underlying implementation; how the elements are actually stored.
3. `vector.cend` - `cend` is a constant iterator pointing to the end. Constant iterators don't let you modify the value pointed to by the iterator.
4. `emplace` - Emplace is like insert except it creates the object "in-place"; you pass emplace the parameters you would pass to the object's constructor.
5. `push_back` - This is to maintain a uniform interface. Some containers like std::list let you push_front
6. Why does `empty()` return a boolean? Shouldn't it be `isEmpty()`?: Should it? Says who? You're used to Python/Scala/Haskell but that's hardly the one true way.
7. Also, the `.begin()` and `.end()` seems inconsistent. `begin()` is a verb while `end()` is a noun in this context. begin denotes to start something whereas it simply returns a pointer to start. Shouldn't the method be called either `start` which is a noun and goes well with "end" or `beginning` atleast instead of `begin`: I suppose. This seems like a petty gripe. It's just the way it is.
8. Why does `list.unique` not return a `set`? It seems weird it not only modifies the data structure (coming from a functional world, it seems really weird to mutate data as side effects) and it is doubly weird here since C++ already has sets. Am I understanding `unique` wrong??: A lot of things will be weird if you carry that mindset of no side-effects into C++. The same open mind that let you learn Python/Scala/Haskell should be applied to C++ if you are serious about learning it. `list.unique` is more like Ruby's `Array#uniq`. From the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/unique/):

> Notice that an element is only removed from the list container if it compares equal to the element immediately preceding it. Thus, this function is especially useful for sorted lists.

As described, returning a set would lose information because it wouldn't preserve duplicates in the case where they are not consecutive.

Like I said, if you're serious about learning C++ you'll have to deal with some of these language/library design decisions. Many of these points seem like petty gripes to me. Some of these are "just the way it is". Some things in C++ are straight up crazy, but if you're serious about C++ what are you going to do? Indeed, Haskell for example seems to have a more straightforward design that "naturally follows," but that's a different kind of language. Hopefully you can get over this.

Answer (score 2):

in C++, the naming strategy is quite different from those other languages.
But as you mentioned, they named the function `push_back` simply because in some containers like `deque` has `push_front` (it is a double end co
ntrainer).
And we use functions like `clear` to empty a container instead of `empty`.
Also, in C++, the set container is ordered. It sorts out the elements in O(nlogn) times by average.

Comment: This begs the questions, why `push_front` - `append` and `prepend` are single word verbs. And as I said, in math, sets are implicitly unordered - why not call the ordered set `ordered_set` instead of `set` and call the `unordered_set` simply `set` -- seems more consistent with notions of a set.

Comment: @wrick `set` came first; it is easier to implement it as an ordered container.

Answer (score 1):

For `unique` in particular, it's about efficiency; it should in fact be called `compact`. It compacts consecutive equal elements into a single element, which can be done in O(n), where as returning a `set` would be O(n log n), and incur the cost of construction and moving objects around.

Answer (score 1):

> vector - vector is such a odd thing to call a list or sequence of things. Why vector?

C++ also has `std::list<T>` which is a doubly linked list. I sort of agree it could be called array but then again it is not fixed size.

> unordered_set - Why not simply a set? Since when are sets ordered? Doesn't set implictly mean order does not matter and the ordered version (java's TreeSets) should be explicitly called ordered_set instead??

C++03 already has `std::set<T>` which is ordered set based on search trees. C++11 has added `unordered_set<T>`, which is based on hash tables. There was a need to distinguish the ordered set named `set` and the new `unordered_set`.

> vector.cend - What does cend mean? I could not find cend in the English dictionary? Why not simply call it end?

The `end()` member function returns `iterator` or `const_iterator` depending on context. The `cend()` function always returns `const_iterator`. This is useful in some situations.

> emplace - What does emplace mean? Shouldn't a better word be "insert"?

There is already existing `insert()` member function which takes value of type `T`. `emplace()` is different, its arguments are passed directly to the constructor of the `T` type and the `T` value is constructed in-place at the right spot in the container.

> push_back - Why not simply call push or append? Isn't the "back" part implicit?

This is likely for parity with `std::deque`'s `push_front()`.

> Why does empty() return a boolean? Shouldn't it be isEmpty()?

The C++ standard library does not use camel case anywhere. This would violate the overall style. Neither does it use this `is_foo()` style.

> Also, the .begin() and .end() seems inconsistent. begin() is a verb while end() is a noun in this context. begin denotes to start something whereas it simply returns a pointer to start. Shouldn't the method be called either start which is a noun and goes well with "end" or beginning atleast instead of begin

I am not a native English speaker but I believe both begin and end can be interpreted as both nouns and verbs.

> Why does list.unique not return a set? It seems weird it not only modifies the data structure (coming from a functional world, it seems really weird to mutate data as side effects) and it is doubly weird here since C++ already has sets. Am I understanding unique wrong??

Operating on `std::list` with existing non-member functions (`std::unique()`) could be less efficient. `std::list` also provides `sort()` member function to optimize sort. (It is possible to sort doubly linked lists in place in O(n * log n) time.)